# Java - Adding multiple user inputs into arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to read an infinite amount of numbers input on the same line from user (separated by a space) and print the square of all values above 0 - all without using for loops.

For example...

Input:

1 2 3 4 -10 -15

Output:

30

Below is the code I have so far:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //insert into array if > 0
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    if(x > 0){
        numbers.add(x);
    }

    //square numbers array
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
        numbers.set(i, numbers.get(i) * numbers.get(i));
    }

    //sum array
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i){
        sum += numbers.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

As you can see I am just scanning one input from the user as i'm not sure how to tackle storing infinite input. Furthermore, I am using for loops for my two equations.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `split` and then calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the first answer, you don't need an ArrayList.

But if you insisted on doing it that way, here is a solution:

To store the numbers, use this code:

```
while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    if(x > 0){
        numbers.add(x);
    }
}
```

And the for loops can be avoided this way:

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
    numbers.set(i, numbers.get(i) * numbers.get(i));
}
```

You can use:

```
List<Integer> newNumbers = numbers.stream().map(x->x*x).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Hi, this produces an error 'lambda expression cannot re declare another variable' and 'the method toList() is undefined for the test type

Comment: @Gareth Hi, the first error is caused by the `x` in the lambda, you should rename it to something else, for example `num->num*num`. For the `toList` error use `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're adding the square of each number, you don't really need any list, just a single number to which you add the square for each number you read from the input. Something like:

```
int result = 0;    
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    if(num > 0)
        result += num * num;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. two things... When I run this and print/store the output e.g I/P: 5 5 5 & O/P: 25 50 75... how could I print/store the sum of the squares i.e 75 as shown above? Also, if I input: 1 -1 nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your program using array list in this way:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNextInt()){
   int x = in.nextInt();
    if(x > 0){
        numbers.add(x * x);
    }
}
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
    sum += numbers.get(i);
}
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` after reading the line and then perform your calculation:

```
        int result = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String a[] = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (String aa : a) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(aa) > 0) {
                result = result + Integer.parseInt(aa) * Integer.parseInt(aa);
            }
        }
System.out.println(result);
```

**I/P:**  2 3 1 -44 -22

***O/P***  14

Answer (score 0):

Using lambdas :

```
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        if (x > 0) {
            numbers.add(x);
        }
    }

    int sum = numbers.stream().map(i -> i * i).reduce((xx, yy) -> xx + yy).get();
    System.out.println(sum);
```